# Creating associated has_many :through records with nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many-through

Here are the models in my many-to-many relationship:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :classrooms, :through => :classroom_memberships
end

class ClassroomMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
  belongs_to :student
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_memberships
  has_many :students, :through => :classroom_memberships
end
```

When creating a new student, I want to give the user the ability to **select multiple classrooms** AND also **create new classrooms** on-the-fly.

(I've been able to get this to work with one-to-many relationships.)

Here's what I currently have in my Student form:

```
<%= f.association :classrooms,
  collection: Classroom.all(order: 'name'),
  prompt: "Choose or type a new classroom name",
  multiple: true,
  input_html: { :class => "shown" } %>
```

This allows me to do this nice multi-select box (using selectize.js):

[image]

When I submit the form, the params that come through are:

```
=> {
     "first_name" => "Tyene",
      "last_name" => "Sand",
       "birthday" => "January 1, 2013",
         "gender" => "F",
       "about_me" => "",
      "family_id" => "1",
  "classroom_ids" => [
    [0] "",
    [1] "1",
    [2] "2"
  ]
}
```

When `Student.new(student_params)` is called, Rails magically knows to create 2 new records in the `classroom_memberships` table and everything is good to go.

### Creating new classrooms on-the-fly

However, if I let the user add a brand new classroom to the list, Rails throws this error:

`Couldn't find all Classrooms with IDs (1, 2, 0) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3)`

Clearly it can't create the `classroom_memberships` record without FIRST creating a new `classroom` for the third item in the select list.

### My question:

**How (or where) can I insert some code to check the list of `classroom_ids` in the params and create the `classroom` record before Rails checks to see if the `classroom_id` exists?**

I tried putting code in the `classroom_membershp.rb` model like this:

```
  def classroom_id=(val)
    # if we've got an integer, they selected an existing record;
    # otherwise, we're creating a brand new one
    if val.numeric?
      write_attribute(:classroom_id, val.to_i)
    else
      create_classroom(:name => val)
    end
  end
```

But the code never gets here! It tries to find the `classroom` via `SELECT` before this point and blows up. This approach has worked for me in one-to-many relationships.

### What I ended up with thanks to the answer from @lx00st:

in `/app/models/student.rb`:

```
  def self.init(params)
    params[:classroom_ids].each_with_index do |c, i|
     # a non-blank, non-numeric classroom ID indicates a new record
     if !c.blank? && !c.numeric?
        params[:classroom_ids][i] = Classroom.create(:name => c).id
      end
    end
    new(params)
  end
```

I'm now calling `Student.init(student_params)` from the `create` and `update` actions.

The only drawback to this approach is that it will create the classroom even if the student creation fails. For my application, that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use some special self.init(params) method in `Student` class

```
def self.init(params)
  if i = params[:classroom_ids].find_index(&:empty?)
    params[:classroom_ids][i] = create_classroom 
  end 
  new(params)
end
```

Comment: OK, I think this could work. I would have to add an iterator here in case multiple new classrooms were being created and `create_classroom` needs params as well.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with the solution I arrived at based on your answer.